What is wrong with the variable?



ID
assigned_to
work_order_id
close_wo_date
close_date
work_order_status
post_code
order_type




611802
John, Ed,Al, Dexter
TMN-09/10/24-2113-0133
2024-10-10 15:24:00.000
2024-10-10 15:23:00.000
Closed
2113
TMN



Datatypes: AutoNumber, Short Text, Short Text, ...
I want to separate the values in the 'assigned_to' column.
However, I get a type mismatch error on line 16.
workOrderId = rstIn!work_order_id

I can't figure out what the problem is.
Option Compare Database

Sub TransformTable()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rstIn As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstOut As DAO.Recordset
    Dim arrParms() As String
    Dim workOrderId() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rstIn = dbs.OpenRecordset("teszt_in", dbOpenForwardOnly)
    Set rstOut = dbs.OpenRecordset("teszt_out", dbOpenDynaset)
    Do While Not rstIn.EOF
        If Not IsNull(rstIn!assigned_to) Then
            arrParms = Split(rstIn!assigned_to, ",")
            workOrderId = rstIn!work_order_id
            For i = 0 To UBound(arrParms)
                rstOut.AddNew
                rstOut!ID = rstIn!ID
                rstOut!assigned_to = arrParms(i)
                rstOut!work_order_id = workOrderId(i)
                rstOut.Update
            Next i
        End If
        rstIn.MoveNext
    Loop
    rstIn.Close
    rstOut.Close
End Sub


It is unclear what the relation is between "I want to separate the values in the 'assigned_to' column" and the error you have.

workOrderId should not be an array, so use:

Dim workOrderId As String

' <snip>

rstOut!work_order_id = workOrderId

' or:

rstOut!work_order_id.Value = workOrderId


You are right, not an array. THX
But the code doesn't even get that far. It reports an error on line 16.

Oh. missed the wrong dim'ing. See edited answer, please.
